# ms access sql LIKE query issue with multiple LIKEs ( VB -> ADODB )

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm querying some exercises from a database in a per page basis. The page information is included in the description of the exercise. So, ExerciseDescription is like this:

```
p. 72. do this and that...
p.72. do this and the other thing...
p. 70. this is yet another exercise...
```

so to accomodate for the lack of space between the p. and the actual number the query goes like this:

```
dbExerRecordSet.Filter = "ChapterID=100196 AND ExerciseType='School' AND (ExerciseDescription LIKE 'p. 72*' OR ExerciseDescription LIKE 'p.72*')"
```

but i got this error:

```
ADODB.Recordset<br/><b>Description:</b> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another
```

So I thought that there is something wrong with the dot character, thus i transformed the query into:

```
dbExerRecordSet.Filter = "ChapterID=100196 AND ExerciseType='School' AND (ExerciseDescription LIKE 'p[.] 72*' OR ExerciseDescription LIKE 'p[.]72*')"
```

but i still get the same error. which is weird. If I remove the OR and everything after it i get no error. If i change OR to AND i get NO ERROR ( but also no exercise found of course ).

what is going on?

thanks in advance.

**edit**

```
dbExerRecordSet.Filter = "ChapterID=100196 AND ExerciseType='School' AND (ExerciseDescription LIKE 'p[.]*72*')"
```

the above doesn't throw an error but also doesn't find the two exercises in page 72.

**edit2**: it's not a problem with the asterisk. I exchanged it for % and it does the exact same thing

Answer (score 0):

ADO uses `%` not `*` for the `LIKE` wildcard character.

Comment: no, I just tried it. it throws the same error. It worked OK with the asterisk BEFORE i add the OR ... statement.

Comment: @MIrrorMirror - have you tried adding more brackets (as well as using %), i.e. `"(ChapterID=100196) AND (ExerciseType='School') AND ((ExerciseDescription LIKE 'p. 72%') OR (ExerciseDescription LIKE 'p.72%'))"`?

Comment: @MIrrorMirror - do you get the same error when using a DAO recordset instead? (In that case definitely use an asterisk mind.)

Comment: i solved it by branching the OR so after the OR, i included all of the previous statement since the beginning.